# CSS issue (no floating images) with greyscale jquery plugin and a simple jquery function

Tags: jquery, css, grayscale

i'm using the greyscale jquery plugin to grayscale images on the fly (by Andrew Pryde).

The effetc works like a charm :
http://www.reflexion-graphic.com/projets/forum/jquery/greyscale/1-test-jquery-greyScale-html5.html

But i try to add another jquery function : Show information over image on rollover.

The function works alone but with the plugin i have a css issue. Images are not floating anymore :
http://www.reflexion-graphic.com/projets/forum/jquery/greyscale/3-test-jquery-hover-greyScale-html5.html

Could you help me to find what is wrong in the css ?

source code (css, html, jquery are easy to find in the example).

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you've wrapped the images with captions inside block elements, which span the entire width of their containers.  `float` applies to the grayscaled images, not to their parent elements, so even though all the images are floated, they are no longer siblings of each other; they are siblings of the hover wrappers.

The images are still floated, but they are alone inside their containers (the wrappers), and the wrappers are not floated.

You can add hover captions without any JS: simply add the caption as another element inside each `.gsWrapper` element, and style it to show on hover.

Stripped-down example:

```
<div class="gsWrapper">
  <img class="img_mosaique_cat_projets noir_blanc" src="img/sj-concelles/220x168.jpg" alt="titre projets">
  <canvas class="gsCanvas" height="168" width="220" style="left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px;"></canvas>

  <div class="hide-hover">test content for hover</div>
</div>
```

And the styling:

```
.hide-hover {
  position: absolute;
}

.gsWrapper:not(:hover) .hide-hover { 
  display: none;
}
```

This way you do not have to worry about adjusting all your other styling and JS to accommodate for wrappers around some of the images.

Other demos: using jQuery slideToggle effect to hide/show the captions: http://jsbin.com/idugaw/3/edit

using pure CSS for a slideToggle effect: http://jsbin.com/idugaw/4/edit

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand the issue now "I have wrapped the images with captions inside block elements". I've tried your solutions but still have an issue : the captions are on the same images : http://www.reflexion-graphic.com/projets/forum/jquery/greyscale/4-test-jquery-hover-greyScale-html5.html I agree, i don't need javascript to make a caption but in this case, i would like to have a jquery effet like slideToggle, that's why i'm using jquery

Comment: I've tried a lot of things but without succes.

Finally, i've tried with a <table> and it's ok : 
http://www.reflexion-graphic.com/projets/forum/jquery/greyscale/5-test-jquery-hover-greyScale-html5.html

Also, i've modified the plugin : I've deleted the css property of the gsWrapper : 'position:relative' and 'display:inline-block'

I know, it's not a good practice to use table. What do you think about my technique ?

I would like to do it with css. Also, i can try an other jquery plugin, maybe i can find one which would be easier to modify.

Comment: It's true, it's poor practice to use table for non-tabular data.  I think you are making things unnecessarily difficult for yourself, especially when you have working examples of what you want to do. I've added a pure CSS slideToggle demo to my answer as well.

Comment: I never use <table> for design. In this particular case, it was the only solution i've found. But, i have a better solution. I use an other plugin : Black and white jQuery plug in. Link : http://gianlucaguarini.com/canvas-experiments/jQuery.BlackAndWhite/demo.html Easy to customize, i 've done what i've looked for in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that all you need to do is put the following code into your CSS

```
.imgHover {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

The Image Hover divs are being displayed as "block" so they are trumping the gsWrapper CSS.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried to add your css code but i still have an issue : http://www.reflexion-graphic.com/projets/forum/jquery/greyscale/3-test-jquery-hover-greyScale-html5.html The images are moving on "hover".

Comment: I would try out Tuff's answer then.  It's a little complex, and he seems to have done more analysis than I have.

Comment: Thank's a lot Brian for your help. It's more complexe that I was expecting when i've tried this plugin.